# Echo Class Inside of HTML Tag with PHP

Tags: php, html, apache

Trying to get this piece of code to run:

```
<li><a <? if ($tab=='Home') echo 'class="activetab"' ?> href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Right now, my PHP/Apache on EC2 setup spits out

```
href="/">Home
```

It looks like the php inside the tag is messing up the rendering, and I'd like the tab to be rendered.

The  site is hosted somewhere else and works, so it seems like a configuration issue with either php or apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check your php short tag is open or not?**

In your `php.ini` change the `short_open_tag = Off to short_open_tag = On`.

Comment: That was the problem! ln 229 in /etc/php.ini for those on ec2 , php, and apache.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847072/php-vs-php-echo-whats-the-difference-which-one-is-better-to-use

Answer (score 1):

<? ... ?> – This is called as PHP short tags which will work based on the value set with short_open_tag directive of PHP configuration file.

Otherwise use <?php ... ?> as delimiters which are also preferable, since, PHP code enclosed with in <?php ... ?> could be recognized with other PHP servers independent of the tag related configuration directives.

Answer (score 0):

Try By This Code

```
<li><a <?php if ($tab=='Home') echo 'class="activetab"' ?> href="/">Home</a></li>
```